# How do I change the overflow of a single element, while having the overflow of the body hidden?

Tags: html, css, overflow, frame

The html below should essentially be a list of images aligned vertically on the left. I want the pictures to scroll, but I don't want the rest of the page to scroll. I also want the rest of the page to have a hidden overflow. Is there anyway to do this with just html and css and how?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Scrolling Pictures</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scrollingPictures.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="scroll">
<img class="left" id="image1" src="C:\Users\Shikamaru\Documents\Contwined Coding\Ravel\New Briefcase\images\bradBeachHeart.JPG" alt="Brad at the Lake"/>

<img class="left" id="image2" src="C:\Users\Shikamaru\Documents\Contwined Coding\Ravel\New Briefcase\images\mariaNavi.jpg" alt="Making Maria Na'vi"/>

<img class="left" id="image3" src="C:\Users\Shikamaru\Documents\Contwined Coding\Ravel\New Briefcase\images\mattWaterRun.jpg" alt="Photoshopped Matt"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
overflow:auto;
margin-left:0;
margin-top:0;
}
div#scroll{
border-right:1px solid orange;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
float:left;
width:200px;
overflow:auto;
}
.left{
z-index:inherit;
float:left;
width:200px; 
min-height:200px; /* for modern browsers */
height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
height:200px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
#image1, #image2, #image3{
width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your `#scroll` a height of 100%, and your `body` a `overflow: hidden`:

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:0;
}
div#scroll{
    border-right:1px solid orange;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.left{
    z-index:inherit;
    float:left;
    width:200px; 
    min-height:200px; /* for modern browsers */
    height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
    height:200px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
#image1, #image2, #image3{
    width:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QcHNu/

Comment: Thank you!!! Now I'm going to work on styling the scroll bars. I actually want that div to scroll automatically based on the position of the mouse, but I know that requires some javascript. Thank you so much!!